# Zipping a complete visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio, zip

I feel a bit silly for asking such a simple question but here goes...

I'm trying to send my visual studio 2008 project into a zipped folder so I can upload it for submission - all project files need to be present.

However, although the program works fine before it is zipped, when I zip the folder I'm getting errors saying that certain files cannot be found. My program files have a yellow exclamation mark warning next to them.

I'm guessing the problem is due to missing or moved files but I'm a bit confused how zipping all the contents of a project can cause this problem.

NOTE - I'm trying to open the zipped project using the following file in the zipped folder 'Visual C# Project File' .

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me resolve this problem!

In the meantime, I will continue to look for a way to fix this.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got any dependancies to libraries external to project folder you have zipped, such as dlls in the GAC?

Comment: Most likely, C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp2_appname.zip\appname\appname\appicon.ico

One of the files that cannot be found has the full path above which isnt in my project folder.

Comment: Error 1 Source file 'C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp2_appname.zip\appname\appname\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ') appname - another error

Comment: Is there an easy way to determine dependancies external to the zipped folder?

Comment: It was because I was opening the folder and not unzipping it - doh.